# What is meant by "discontinuous" here?

Tags: signal-processing, continuity

I am reading signal processing first by Mcclellan
In chap 3,last para of article 3.1.2, I came across a term "discontinuous" as shown underlined in attached photo

What is meant by it in the context of discussion in photo?
Is it meaning discrete?

[image]

Comment: An example would be a square wave. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave

Comment: How square wave? My initial understanding is/was that non-continous signal is the one,which has break(gap) between different parts of graph

Comment: In a square wave, the signal jumps back and forth between $-1$ and $1.$  It does not pass though any of the intermediate points.  That is discontinuity.

Comment: I couldn't understand you fully, Actually As we see graph in square wave, while making transition from 1 to _1 or vice versa. There is a straight vertical line which passes through all points between 1 and _1,

Comment: That is something a physicist would do.  From a mathematicians point of view there are no straight vertical lines.  At the jump, the left hand limit does not equal the right hand limit, and that is a discontinuity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means not continuous.

For an example, consider the following function on $[0,2],$ which can be extended to be periodic:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x  &\text{ if } 0\le x\lt 1\\  0& \text{ if } 1\le x\lt 2\end{cases}.$$

The graph of this function would look kind of like this:

......./_/_/_/_/_/........

Comment: that function is discontinuous at $x=1$

Comment: Can you please kindly include figure or graph? So your answer provides a much clear understanding

Comment: Soft reminder please

Comment: Sorry, I'm not much of an artist

Comment: Very nice effort